# Apache Client 4.3.4 with proxy NTLM Auth

Tags: java, apache, authentication, proxy, ntlm

I have to post some data and have to use a proxy with ntlm auth. My problem is, that I get just 407 (Proxy auth required) from proxy. I have no control of the proxy, so I can not debug here!

The client logs shows this proxy states:

1.) Proxy auth state: UNCHALLENGED

2.) Proxy auth state: CHALLENGED

3.) Proxy auth state: HANDSHAKE

---

Perhaps someone can just check my code, if it should work, because I hope that proxy settings are wrong.

```
NTCredentials ntCreds = new NTCredentials(ntUsername, ntPassword,localMachineName, domainName );

    CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
    HttpHost httpProxy = new HttpHost(InetAddress.getByName(proxyString), Integer.valueOf(proxyPort));
    credsProvider.setCredentials( new AuthScope(httpProxy), ntCreds );
    HttpClientBuilder clientBuilder = HttpClientBuilder.create();

    clientBuilder.setProxy(httpProxy);
    clientBuilder.setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider);
    clientBuilder.setProxyAuthenticationStrategy(new ProxyAuthenticationStrategy());

    CloseableHttpClient client = clientBuilder.build();

    URI destination = new URI("http://requestb.in/1bpjk7g");
    HttpEntity entity = new StringEntity("test 123");
    HttpPost request = new HttpPost(destination);
    RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom().setProxy(httpProxy).build();
    request.setConfig(config );
    request.setEntity(entity);
    client.execute(request);
```

Comment: Above should be ok. Proxy configuration seems to be the problem, but I have no control here :-)